# SQLalchemy in Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Im new with SQLalchemy in Python 2.7, I have the next tables with one to one relationship (is right the uselist=False):

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    address = Column(String) 

class Pet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pet'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    owner = relationship("Person", backref=backref("pet", uselist=False))
```

My first question here is if I delete one entry from Pet table will delete the associate entry in Person table?

And my second question is how can I get the address in some entry in Pet table, like pet.id, pet.name and person.address (due both tables have one to one relationship).

Answer (score 0):

1. no, depending on the database server it could be defined there or SQL Alchemy can help by defining a ForeignKeyConstraint: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html
2. If your `Pet` instance is named `pet_object`: `pet_object.owner.id`, `pet_object.owner.name` …